# How can I get (using a script) the ID to use with docker exec?

Tags: docker

After a docker image is running, how can I programmatically get the ID so I can script commands for that image?  I think the ID I want is called the `Container ID` because that is how it is listed in the output of the `docker ps` command.

For example, I start the image using `docker run`, I run the `docker ps` command to get the "ID" I want and then I can run `docker logs` or other commands.

```
docker run myImage
docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED 
1234567890    myImage     sleep 120   ...
```

So now that I know the container ID is `1234567890`, I can run commands on the container.

```
docker logs 1234567890
docker exec -it 1234567890 bash
```

How can I get that ID programmatically (assuming that there is only one instance of that image currently running).

I tried this command that I thought would work but it did not.

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}' myImage
sha256:95e11.....
```

See also https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples.

I think the inspect only inspecting the "image" not the instance running (aka the container).

I hope I have the terminology right, but if not let me know and I'll fix it.

NOTE: If it matters, the script is a bash script on Linux.

Comment: Running `docker inspect myImage` will give you information about the *image*, not the container that you've started.

Comment: Why don't you directly assign a name to your container instance (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name)? You'll could exec commands on the container instance by name then.

Comment: @Ass3mbler, thanks for the suggestion.  I googled and found this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/naming-docker-containers-3-tips-for-beginners which was helpful as well.

Comment: @PatS glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start a detached container (`docker run -d ...`), the docker client will emit the container ID on stdout.  So you can do something like:

```
$ CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -d myImage)
$ docker exec $CONTAINER_ID somecommand
```

If you assign your container a name, you can use that in place of the container ID:

```
$ docker run --name myContainer myImage
$ docker exec myContainer somecommand
```

If you simply want the ID of the most recent container you launched, you can use `docker ps -lq`:

```
$ CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -lq)
$ docker exec $CONTAINER_ID somecommand
```

If there is only a single container running from a given image, you can run something like:

```
$ CONTAINER_ID=$(docker container ps --filter ancestor=myImage -q)
$ docker exec $CONTAINER_ID somecommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do in this way

```
for container_id in $(docker ps  --filter="name=$myImage" -q -a);do docker rm $container_id;done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get container ID by filtering which created from particular image.

```
docker ps -qf "ancestor=imagename"
```

`ancestor`: filter containers which share a given image as an ancestor

`-q`: output only the ID

`-f`: for [filtering](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)

`-l`: show the latest